# angular.js:12520 Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'clickable' is not a function, got undefined

Tags: angularjs

Now I have read that angular doesn't allow global controllers but I don't believe I am making it global. What is even more odd is that I even created a script in the HTML file and it gave me the same error. I am positive that code should have worked.

I am using Intellij and used its template to generate a small boiler plate via bower.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html lang="en" ng-app="myApp" class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html lang="en" ng-app="myApp" class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html lang="en" ng-app="myApp" class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html lang="en" ng-app="myApp" class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>My AngularJS App</title>
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/html5-boilerplate/dist/css/normalize.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/html5-boilerplate/dist/css/main.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css">
  <script src="bower_components/html5-boilerplate/dist/js/vendor/modernizr-2.8.3.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApplication">

  <ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="#/view1">view1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#/view2">view2</a></li>
  </ul>

  <div ng-controller="clickable">

    <input type="button" value="Click Me" ng-click="clickMe()">
      {{clickable.click}}

  </div>

  <!--[if lt IE 7]>
      <p class="browsehappy">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience.</p>
  <![endif]-->

  <div ng-view></div>

  <div>Angular seed app: v<span app-version></span></div>

  <!-- In production use:
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/x.x.x/angular.min.js"></script>
  -->
  <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
  <script src="view1/view1.js"></script>
  <script src="view2/view2.js"></script>
  <script src="components/version/version.js"></script>
  <script src="components/version/version-directive.js"></script>
  <script src="components/version/interpolate-filter.js"></script>
  <script src="controllers/clickablecontroller.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

clickablecontroller.js

```
angular.module('myApplication',[])
    .controller('clickable',['$scope', function($scope){
        $scope.clickMe = function(){
            $scope.click = click++;
        }
    }]);
```

----------------UPDATE 1 -----------
app.js

```
'use strict';

// Declare app level module which depends on views, and components
angular.module('myApp', [
  'ngRoute',
  'myApp.view1',
  'myApp.view2',
  'myApp.version'
]).
config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/view1'});
}]);
```

[image: Error]

Comment: it depends on what you have in app.js

Comment: Not sure from the details you've given, but you might try to remove the `,[]` part from the module part in clickablecontroller.js. So it will become `angular.module('myApplication').controller(...)`. With the square brackets you are redefining the app, without the square brackets, you are referencing the existing one.

Comment: Also you created two elements with `ng-app` tags, try to remove an odd one

Comment: @AlexSzabó please see update 1. I tried to take out the , [ ] and that did not work either. Same error

Answer (score 0):

clickable is your controller. If you want to output value of click property you need {{click}}. Angular will know what the controller is and show to value of click property of $scope in that controller.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try this:

```
var myModule = angular.module('myApplication', []);
myModule.controller('clickable', function ($scope) {
    $scope.clickMe = function(){
        $scope.click = click++;
    }
});
```

Besides,

use `{{click}}` to instead of `{{clickable.click}}`

Comment: That did not work and I have read that using your above method is bad practice.

Comment: @Drew1208 I'm sorry that my advice didn't help you, but I didn't realise that it is a bad practice. I wrote this in the way I learnt from [Angular tutorial](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_02) , may you show me where did you read about that?

Comment: @Drew1208 I didn't realize that you have used myApp as you ng-app. I wonder is this mistake makes you think it is a bad practice. I edited the answer, you can try it again.

Comment: I have been using a tutorial sponsored by google. http://campus.codeschool.com/courses/shaping-up-with-angular-js/intro.. In the advanced tutorial they talk a little about why it's bad and using the method I am attempting to use.

Answer (score 0):

I had to had my new module in my apps.js file.

```
'use strict';

// Declare app level module which depends on views, and components
angular.module('myApp', [
  'ngRoute',
  'myApp.view1',
  'myApp.view2',
  'myApp.version',
  'myApplication'
]).
config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/view1'});
}]);
```

Then I had to declare click as a variable like so:

```
angular.module('myApplication',[])
    .controller('clickable',['$scope', function($scope){
        console.log("I am in the controller")
        var click = 0
        $scope.clickMe = function(){
            $scope.click = click++;
        }
    }]);
```

Then in my index.html file I could simply use:

```
<div ng-controller="clickable">

    <input type="button" value="Click Me" ng-click="clickMe()">
      {{click}}

  </div>
```

Comment: you created two ng application modules, `angular.module('myApp', [...])` and `angular.module('myApplication',[])` with tags `<body ng-app="myApplication">` and `<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html lang="en" ng-app="myApp" class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->` respectively. Leave only one. Then put your `myApplication` module to you `myApp` namespace, e.g. replace `angular.module('myApplication',[])` with `angular.module('myApp.clickable',[])`. And change module name in dependency  from `'myApplication'` to `myApp.clickable`